# Send binary file over TCP/IP connection

Tags: c++, c, file-io, malloc, winsock

I will rephrase the whole question here so that it is answerable.

I am able to copy binary file perfectly in the same machine not using sockets but just making a simple copy function. Trying to implement this code for copying onto a TCP/IP connection but can't get it to work.

```
FILE *filehandle = fopen("imagefile.jpg", "rb");
FILE *dest  =fopen("imagecopy.jpg", "wb");    // copied image file
fseek(filehandle, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long filesize = ftell(filehandle);
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*filesize);
rewind(filehandle);
int bytesread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), filesize, filehandle);
for( int i=0; i<filesize; i++ )
{
    fputc(buffer[i], filehandle);    // copies all the contents to dest
}
```

The code above works perfectly for copying an image file in the computer but when implemented to copy on server, it is difficult to go about it.

I am trying to send an image file from a **server** to a **client** both which have been made manually in C. The length of the file to be sent by the server is only known to the server when it's sending the file so the buffer is dynamically generated in the server, something like this:

**SERVER**

```
fseek(filehandle, 0, SEEK_END);
long filesize = ftell(filehandle);    // file could be 11000bytes
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*filesize);    // char buffer with 11000 bytes to store the data from the file.
// then I call the send() function
rewind(filehandle);    // go back to beginning
send(clientsocket, buffer, filesize, 0);    // this is being sent perfectly, no errors because in the actual code, I am checking for errors
```

**CLIENT**

```
// here is where I don't understand how to dynamically allocate the 11000 bytes to store the data in a client buffer
// the filesize is not necessarily going to be 11000 so need to dynamically allocate
// I did the following:
#define BUFSIZE 10
FILE *filehandle = fopen("imagefile.jpg", "wb");    // image file created by client
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
int bytesread = recv(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), 0);
if( bytesread > 0 )
{
    printf("Bytes read: %d\n", bytesread);    // bytes read is 5
    printf("Buffer: %s\n", buffer);    // but buffer shows all the binary text like it normally would
    // when I try to store buffer in a file, it doesn't put full buffer because only 5 characters are written
    for( int i=0; i<bytesread; i++ )
    {
        fputc(buffer[i], filehandle);    // this doesn't create full image
    }
}
```

**How can I dynamically allocate the 11000 bytes sent by the server?**

Comment: you're asking why code that you didn't show doesn't work?

Comment: Undefined behavior is exactly that – _undefined_.  It is not required to crash.

Comment: it's unclear why you are using `printf("%s"` to display an image file

Comment: and `sizeof bufffer` is the size of the pointer, not the block of memory it points to.

Comment: @SLaks This isn't quite UB if he fixed the `sizeof bufffer` part - it wouldn't actually overrun since the code passed the length of the small allocated buffer (or at least, attempted to) to `recv`.

Comment: Have the server send the file size first, then the client can use that to decide the size of the buffer to allocate.

Comment: @T.C., i thought of that but it's not going to work because then I would still need to allocate the `char` for incoming filesize length, i need to know exact size to get the image file correctly over the server to client.

Comment: @Hawk: it WILL work. You DO NOT (and SHOULD NOT) allocate a single buffer to send/receive the entire file content at one time. Especially for large files. Handle it in fixed-length chunks instead. Even the variable that holds the filesize itself can be treated as a fixed-sized buffer. See my answer for an example.  It sends the filesize followed by the file data, then reads the filesize followed by the file data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to loop both the sending and receiving.  Neither `send()` nor `recv()` are guaranteed to send/read as many bytes as you requested.

You also should send the file size before the file data so the receiver knows how many bytes to expect and when to stop reading.

Try something more like this:

SERVER

```
bool senddata(SOCKET sock, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    unsigned char *pbuf = (unsigned char *) buf;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int num = send(sock, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (num == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                // optional: use select() to check for timeout to fail the send
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }

        pbuf += num;
        buflen -= num;
    }

    return true;
}

bool sendlong(SOCKET sock, long value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return senddata(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
}

bool sendfile(SOCKET sock, FILE *f)
{
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long filesize = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    if (filesize == EOF)
        return false;
    if (!sendlong(sock, filesize))
        return false;
    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        do
        {
            size_t num = min(filesize, sizeof(buffer));
            num = fread(buffer, 1, num, f);
            if (num < 1)
                return false;
            if (!senddata(sock, buffer, num, 0))
                return false;
            filesize -= num;
        }
        while (filesize > 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
FILE *filehandle = fopen("imagefile.jpg", "rb");
if (filehandle != NULL)
{
    sendfile(clientsocket, filehandle);
    fclose(filehandle);
}
```

CLIENT

```
bool readdata(SOCKET sock, void *buf, int buflen)
{
    unsigned char *pbuf = (unsigned char *) buf;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        int num = recv(sock, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (num == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                // optional: use select() to check for timeout to fail the read
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }
        else if (num == 0)
            return false;

        pbuf += num;
        buflen -= num;
    }

    return true;
}

bool readlong(SOCKET sock, long *value)
{
    if (!readdata(sock, value, sizeof(value)))
        return false;
    *value = ntohl(*value);
    return true;
}

bool readfile(SOCKET sock, FILE *f)
{
    long filesize;
    if (!readlong(sock, &filesize))
        return false;
    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        char buffer[1024];
        do
        {
            int num = min(filesize, sizeof(buffer));
            if (!readdata(sock, buffer, num))
                return false;
            int offset = 0;
            do
            {
                size_t written = fwrite(&buffer[offset], 1, num-offset, f);
                if (written < 1)
                    return false;
                offset += written;
            }
            while (offset < num);
            filesize -= num;
        }
        while (filesize > 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

```
FILE *filehandle = fopen("imagefile.jpg", "wb");
if (filehandle != NULL)
{
    bool ok = readfile(clientsocket, filehandle);
    fclose(filehandle);

    if (ok)
    {
        // use file as needed...
    }
    else
        remove("imagefile.jpg");
}
```

Comment: won't the buffer 1024 be too small for the filesize sent by the server?

Comment: No, because the receiver is looping, reading in 1024 byte chunks, until the end of the file has been received.

Comment: You need to stop trying to allocate a buffer to hold the entire file at one time.  One, that is not efficient.  Two, it wastes time and memory for large files.  Send the source file in chunks as you are reading from it.  Write the target file in chunks as you are receiving it.

Comment: I get the code now @RemyLebeau, I understand how it works but I found a different way to do it. Simply send a header first just as T.C described. It works fine and this code is good, too so i'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: This saved me quite a lot of frustration, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Great and enriching answer! It's a bit unfortunate that the author of the post has been voted negatively. He writes on this forum asking for help and although his question has some criticisms, his post led an useful answer like this

Answer (score 3):

We could avoid the header that contains the image size, but we just read to the end of the sent data. About the buffer size, we could use a fixed number such as 10 * 1024, when we received some data from the server, we just save it into a file according to the actual received data length.

```
// please open a file ...
FILE * fp;
// ...
const int LENGTH = 10 * 1024;

int len = 0;
char * buffer = (char *)malloc(LENGTH);
while ((len = recv(socket, buffer, LENGTH, 0)) > 0) {
    fwrite(buffer, 1, len, fp);
}
free(buffer);
// close the file
```

@T.C: I guess we cannot allocate a buffer according to the size sent from the server in case the image is too large to save inside the client's memory. Not mention the server is fake, and intended to make any attack.

Comment: the memory allocated by LENGTH is 10240 bytes, i presume..but the image file is 11656 bytes, this will cause the file not to be copied fully.

Comment: @Hawk: You keep posting comments that suggest you DO NOT understand how loops work. Is that really the case? If so, you need to stop what you are doing and go back to learning fundamental programming basics. This code will keep reading, in `LENGTH` chunks, writing each chunk to `fp`, until either the socket is closed or `recv()` fails with an error.  That means this code requires the sender to close the socket when it is done sending the file, without sending the file size beforehand.