# winsock send/recv txt file wrong data

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

i'm new to program winsock , i have this code : server run , then we run the client "client localhost" from cmd , the file is sent from client to server sometimes the server receive the txt file wit correct data sometimes not and i found something like garbage or wrong data , so please help me , i will post the codes :

Server :

```
#undef UNICODE
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN


#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
 #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
using namespace std;


#define DEFAULT_PORT "1234"

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;


    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    // printf("iResult : %d\n", iResult);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    //printf("again :iResult : %d\n", iResult);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
//  printf("if error no showed we continue ", iResult);
    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("accepting ", iResult);

    // No longer need server socket
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection


        ///////recive a file //////// 
          int Size;
    char *Filesize = new char[1024];

    if(recv(ClientSocket, Filesize, 1024, 0)) // File size
    {
        Size = atoi((const char*)Filesize);
        printf("File size: %d\n", Size);
    }


    char *Buffer = new char[Size];
    int bytes_read;
    /////////////test code start


    while (1) {
        // Read data into buffer.  We may not have enough to fill up buffer, so we
        // store how many bytes were actually read in bytes_read.
        bytes_read = recv(ClientSocket, Buffer, Size, 0);
        if (bytes_read == 0) // We're done reading from the file
        {   
            Buffer[Size]='\0';
             FILE *File;
        File = fopen("F:\\file2.txt", "wb");
        fwrite((const char*)Buffer, 1, Size, File);
        //string str=string(Buffer);
        //printf(str);

        //std::cout<<str;
        fclose(File);
            break;
        }

        if (bytes_read < 0) {
            // handle errors
            cout << "file read error";
        }

    }

    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Client :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

using namespace std;


#define DEFAULT_PORT "1234"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;

    int iResult;


    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }



    //Send A File ///
    FILE *File;
        char *Buffer;
        unsigned long Size;

        File = fopen("E:\\file1.txt", "rb");

    //File = fopen("file1.txt", "rb");
        if(!File)
        {
            printf("Error while readaing the file\n");

        }

    fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
        Size = ftell(File);
        fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);

    Buffer = new char[Size];

        fread(Buffer, Size, 1, File);
        char cSize[MAX_PATH];
        sprintf(cSize, "%i", Size);
        //printf("file size is %s ",cSize);
        fclose(File);
        //Buffer[Size]='\0';
        send(ConnectSocket, cSize, MAX_PATH, 0); // File size

        send(ConnectSocket, Buffer, Size, 0); // File Binary
        ZeroMemory(&Buffer, sizeof(Buffer));

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent


    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing you're sending the file size as a 255 byte string but reading it as a 1000 byte string - it would actually be more sensible to send it as 4 bytes of binary data, but if you're going to use a string you at least need to make the lengths match.  But more importantly you're not handling the case where the data is split into more than one read properly; you are reading the data into the beginning of the buffer, even if there is already data there.  There may be other problems, but that's the most obvious.

Comment: @HarryJohnston i'm sending the size of the file first then i'm sending the file , the file received with the same size ,but different data ! if you can show me the change in the code I'll appreciate  that a lot !

Comment: You write `Size` bytes of data to the file regardless of whether you've actually read that much data into the buffer, so that's as expected.  You need to track how many bytes you've received so far so that you know what point in the buffer the next `recv` call should start from.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send binary file over TCP/IP connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634483/send-binary-file-over-tcp-ip-connection)

Answer (score 0):

As @HarryJohnston said in comments, your `send()` and `recv()` are mismatched.  You are sending the file size as a variable-length string using a 260-byte buffer, then using a 1000-byte buffer to receive it (which is going to receive both the file size and a portion of the file data) and convert that entire buffer to an integer regardless of how many characters were used to format the string value.  So the first thing you need to do is stop sending the file size as a variable-length string in the first place, and instead send it as a fixed-length binary integer.  Then the receiver knows exactly how many bytes to read to receive the file size, and can then finish reading however many bytes the integer says to read.

You are also ignore return values, not checking for errors, not accounting for `send()` and `recv()` transferring fewer bytes than requested, and generally not managing the file data correctly.

Try something more like this:

Server :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "1234"

bool readData(SOCKET sock, void *buff, int buflen)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buff;
    int bytes_read;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        bytes_read = recv(sock, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (bytes_read <= 0)
        {
            if (bytes_read == SOCKET_ERROR)
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            else
                printf("client disconnected\n");

            return false;
        }

        pbuf += bytes_read;
        buflen -= bytes_read;
    }

    return true;        
}

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    // printf("iResult : %d\n", iResult);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    // Resolve the server address and port
    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;

    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    //printf("again :iResult : %d\n", iResult);
    if ( iResult != 0 )
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for listening for client
    SOCKET ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // start listening
    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, 1);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("client connected\n");

    // Receive until the peer sends a file or shuts down the connection

    unsigned long FileSize;
    if (!readData(ClientSocket, &FileSize, sizeof(FileSize)))
    {
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    FileSize = ntohl(FileSize);
    printf("File size: %lu\n", FileSize);

    FILE *File = fopen("F:\\file2.txt", "wb");
    if (!File)
    {
        printf("fopen failed with error\n");
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (FileSize > 0)
    {
        char Buffer[1024];
        int bytes_to_read;

        do
        {
            if (FileSize <= sizeof(Buffer))
                bytes_to_read = (int)FileSize;
            else
                bytes_to_read = sizeof(Buffer);

            if (!readData(ClientSocket, Buffer, bytes_to_read))
            {
                fclose(File);
                remove("F:\\file2.txt");
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                closesocket(ListenSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            if (fwrite(Buffer, bytes_to_read, 1, File) != 1)
            {
                printf("fwrite failed with error\n");
                fclose(File);
                remove("F:\\file2.txt");
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                closesocket(ListenSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            FileSize -= bytes_to_read;
        }
        while (FileSize > 0);
    }    

    fclose(File);
    printf("file received\n");

    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Client :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "1234"

bool sendData(SOCKET sock, void *buff, int buflen)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buff;
    int bytes_sent;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        bytes_sent = send(sock, pbuf, buflen, 0);
        if (bytes_sent <= 0)
        {
            if (bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            else
                printf("client disconnected\n");

            return false;
        }

        pbuf += bytes_sent;
        buflen -= bytes_sent;
    }

    return true;        
}

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    for(struct addrinfo *ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {    
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            break;

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //Send A File ///

    FILE *File = fopen("E:\\file1.txt", "rb");
    if (!File)
    {
        printf("fopen failed with error\n");
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END) != 0)
    {
        printf("fseek failed with error\n");
        fclose(File);
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned long FileSize = ftell(File);
    if (FileSize == EOF)
    {
        printf("Error getting the file size\n");
        fclose(File);
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //printf("file size is %lu\n", FileSize);

    if (fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
    {
        printf("fseek failed with error\n");
        fclose(File);
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned long tmpFileSize = htonl(FileSize);
    if (!sendData(ConnectSocket, &tmpFileSize, sizeof(tmpFileSize)))
    {
        fclose(File);
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (FileSize > 0)
    {
        char Buffer[1024];
        int bytes_to_send;

        do
        {
            if (FileSize <= sizeof(Buffer))
                bytes_to_send = (int)FileSize;
            else
                bytes_to_send = sizeof(Buffer);

            if (fread(Buffer, bytes_to_send, 1, File) != 1)
            {
                printf("fread failed with error\n");
                fclose(File);
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            if (!sendData(ConnectSocket, Buffer, bytes_to_send))
            {
                fclose(File);
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            FileSize -= bytes_to_send;
        }
        while (FileSize > 0);
    }

    fclose(File);
    printf("file sent\n");

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent

    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_BOTH);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you really should stop mixing C and C++ together, use one or the other, not both.  Here is a C++ version of the above code:

Server :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "1234"

void winsockError(const char *func, int errcode)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << func << " failed with error: " << errcode;
    throw std::runtime_error(oss.str());
}

void winsockError(const char *func)
{
    winsockError(func, WSAGetLastError());
}

struct WSAInit
{
    WSAInit()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        // std::cout << "iResult : " << iResult << endl;
        if (iResult != 0)
            winsockError("WSAStartup", iResult);
    }

    ~WSAInit()
    {
        WSACleanup();
    }
};

struct Socket
{
    SOCKET sckt;

    Socket(SOCKET sock) : sckt(sock)
    {
    }

    Socket(int family, int socktype, int protocol)
    {
        sckt = socket(family, socktype, protocol);
        if (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET)
            winsockError("socket");
    }

    ~Socket()
    {
        Close();
    }

    void Close()
    {
        if (sckt != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            closesocket(sckt);
            sckt = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }

    void Bind(sockaddr *addr, int addrlen)
    {
        if (bind(sckt, addr, addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            winsockError("bind");
    }

    void Listen(int Backlog)
    {
        if (listen(sckt, Backlog) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            winsockError("listen");
    }

    void Accept(sockaddr *addr, int addrlen, Socket &sock)
    {
        sock = accept(sckt, addr, addrlen);
        if (!sock)
            winsockError("accept");
    }

    void Read(void *buff, int buflen)
    {
        char *pbuf = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff);
        int bytes_read;

        while (buflen > 0)
        {
            bytes_read = recv(sckt, pbuf, buflen, 0);
            if (bytes_read == SOCKET_ERROR)
                winsockError("recv");
            if (bytes_read == 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("client disconnected");
            pbuf += bytes_read;
            buflen -= bytes_read;
        }
    }

    void Shutdown(int which)
    {
        if (shutdown(sckt, which) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            winsockError("shutdown");
    }

    bool operator !() const
    {
        return (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET);
    }

    Socket& operator =(SOCKET sock)
    {
        Close();
        sckt = sock;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct AddrInfo
{
    addrinfo *ai;

    AddrInfo() : ai(NULL) {}

    ~AddrInfo()
    {
        if (ai)
            freeaddrinfo(ai);
    }

    addrinfo* operator->() { return ai; }
    addrinfo** operator&() { return &ai; }
};

int __cdecl main(void) 
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize Winsock
        WSAInit wsa;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        addrinfo hints = {0};
        AddrInfo result;

        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        int iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        //std::cout << "again :iResult : " << iResult << std::endl;
        if (iResult != 0)
            winsockError("getaddrinfo", iResult);

        // Create a SOCKET for listening for client
        Socket ListenSocket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

        // Setup the listening socket
        ListenSocket.Bind(result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

        // start listening
        ListenSocket.Listen(1);

        // Accept a client socket
        Socket ClientSocket;
        ListenSocket.Accept(NULL, 0, ClientSocket);
        std::cout << "client connected" << std::endl;

        // Receive until the peer sends a file or shuts down the connection

        unsigned long FileSize;
        ClientSocket.Read(&FileSize, sizeof(FileSize));
        FileSize = ntohl(FileSize);
        std::cout << "File size: " << FileSize << std::endl;

        std::ofstream File("F:\\file2.txt" std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::binary);
        if (!File)
            throw std::runtime_error("ofstream failed with error");

        if (FileSize > 0)
        {
            char Buffer[1024];
            int bytes_to_read;

            do
            {
                bytes_to_read = std::min(FileSize, sizeof(Buffer));

                ClientSocket.Read(Buffer, bytes_to_read);

                if (!File.write(Buffer, bytes_to_read))
                    throw std::runtime_error("write failed with error");

                FileSize -= bytes_to_read;
            }
            while (FileSize > 0);    
        }

        File.close();
        std::cout << "file received" << std::endl;

        ClientSocket.Shutdown(SD_BOTH);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Client :

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "1234"

void winsockError(const char *func, int errcode)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << func << " failed with error: " << errcode;
    throw std::runtime_error(oss.str());
}

void winsockError(const char *func)
{
    winsockError(func, WSAGetLastError());
}

struct WSAInit
{
    WSAInit()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        // std::cout << "iResult : " << iResult << std::endl;
        if (iResult != 0)
            winsockError("WSAStartup", iResult);
    }

    ~WSAInit()
    {
        WSACleanup();
    }
};

struct Socket
{
    SOCKET sckt;

    Socket() : sckt(INVALID_SOCKET) {}

    Socket(SOCKET sock) : sckt(sock) {}

    ~Socket()
    {
        Close();
    }

    void Create(int family, int socktype, int protocol)
    {
        Close();
        sckt = socket(family, socktype, protocol);
        if (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET)
            winsockError("socket");
    }

    void Close()
    {
        if (sckt != INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            closesocket(sckt);
            sckt = INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
    }

    bool Connect(sockaddr *addr, int addrlen)
    {
        return (connect(sckt, addr, addrlen) != SOCKET_ERROR);
    }

    void Send(void *buff, int buflen)
    {
        char *pbuf = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buff);
        int bytes_sent;

        while (buflen > 0)
        {
            bytes_sent = send(sckt, pbuf, buflen, 0);
            if (bytes_sent == SOCKET_ERROR)
                winsockError("send");
            if (bytes_sent == 0)
                throw std::runtime_error("client disconnected");
            pbuf += bytes_sent;
            buflen -= bytes_sent;
        }
    }

    void Shutdown(int which)
    {
        if (shutdown(sckt, which) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            winsockError("shutdown");
    }

    bool operator !() const { return (sckt == INVALID_SOCKET); }
};

struct AddrInfo
{
    addrinfo *ai;

    AddrInfo() : ai(NULL) {}

    ~AddrInfo()
    {
        if (ai)
            freeaddrinfo(ai);
    }

    addrinfo* operator->() { return ai; }
    addrinfo** operator&() { return &ai; }
};

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    try
    {
        // Validate the parameters
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "usage: " << argv[0] << " server-name";
            throw std::runtime_error(oss.str());
        }

        // Initialize Winsock
        WSAInit wsa;

        addrinfo hints = {0};
        AddrInfo result;

        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        int iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
            winsockError("getaddrinfo", iResult);

        // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
        Socket ConnectSocket;
        for(addrinfo *ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
        {    
            // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
            ConnectSocket.Create(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

            // Connect to server.
            if (ConnectSocket.Connect(ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen))
                break;

            ConnectSocket.Close();
        }

        if (!ConnectSocket)
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to connect to server!");

        //Send A File ///

        std::ifstream File("E:\\file1.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
        if (!File)
            throw std::runtime_error("ifstream failed with error");

        File.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
        if (!File)
            throw std::runtime_error("seekg failed with error");

        unsigned long FileSize = File.tellg();
        if (!File)
            throw std::runtime_error("tellg() failed with error");

        //std::cout << "file size is " << FileSize << std::endl;

        File.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
        if (!File)
            throw std::runtime_error("seekg failed with error");

        unsigned long tmpFileSize = htonl(FileSize);
        ConnectSocket.Send(&tmpFileSize, sizeof(tmpFileSize));

        if (FileSize > 0)
        {
            char Buffer[1024];
            int bytes_to_send;

            do
            {
                bytes_to_send = std::min(FileSize, sizeof(Buffer));

                if (!File.read(Buffer, bytes_to_send))
                    throw std::runtime_error("read failed with error");

                ConnectSocket.Send(Buffer, bytes_to_send);

                FileSize -= bytes_to_send;
            }
            while (FileSize > 0);
        }

        File.close();
        std::cout << "file sent" << std::endl;

        // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent

        ConnectSocket.Shutdown(SD_BOTH);
    }    
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay , the first code you modify still give the same result , the second code (c++ ) give errors i think it's related to the definition of socket some vars like ListenSocket , ClientSocket , ios_base and other hope you fix the code .

all regards

Comment: I fixed a couple of typos, and make a few tweaks. But the core logic should work.  If you are having problems with it, you need to explain what they are.

Comment: the errors in your c++ code  : 

1- no suitable conversion function from WSA::Socket  to SOCKET exist ! 
2- namespace std has no member "runtme_error"

3- for  ~WSA()  : no operator "~" matches these operands

Comment: There were a few missing braces in the code.  I fixed that.  I also added some more methods to the `Socket` structs to make them more C++-ish.