# unable to form command using protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following proto file

package DS3DExcite.Cpp.ExternalVariantSwitcher.ProtocolBuffers;

```
message DGCommand
{
    extensions 100 to max;
    enum Type
    {
        AttachModel = 1;
        AttachModelReply = 2;
        ....
        ...
         SwitchVariants = 4;
    }
    required Type type      = 1;
    required uint32 id      = 2;
    optional uint32 replyTo = 3 [default = 0];
    optional string message = 4;
}

message SwitchVariants
{
    extend DGCommand
    {
        required SwitchVariants command = 103;
    }

    message VariantState
    {
        required string variant = 1;
        required string state = 2;
    }

    repeated VariantState variants = 1;
    repeated string variantNames = 2;
    optional string state = 3;

}
```

I compiled the proto file with protobuf 2.4.1 version to generate .pb.h and .pb.cc files

Now I form the commands

```
DS3DExcite::Net::PVCConnector::ProtocolBuffers::DGCommand commandObj;
    commandObj.set_type(DS3DExcite::Net::PVCConnector::ProtocolBuffers::DGCommand_Type_SwitchVariants);
    commandObj.set_id(3);
    DS3DExcite::Net::PVCConnector::ProtocolBuffers::SwitchVariants   *objVarState;
    objVarState = commandObj.MutableExtension(DS3DExcite::Net::PVCConnector::ProtocolBuffers::SwitchVariants::command);
    DS3DExcite::Net::PVCConnector::ProtocolBuffers::SwitchVariants_VariantState *state = objVarState->add_variants();

    state->set_state("OFF");
    state->set_variant("M_Carpaint_3");
```

I serialise the message

```
   int size = commandObj.ByteSize();

    int sizeSize = sizeof(int);

    std::vector<char> data(size ,0);
    memcpy(data.data(), &size, sizeSize);
    data.resize(size + sizeSize );
    commandObj.SerializeToArray(static_cast<void*>(&(data[0])+sizeSize) ,size);
    QByteArray byteArray =  QByteArray::fromRawData(static_cast<const char*>(data.data()), data.size());
```

And I send this message on a Qtcp socket to server which deserializes the message and extract the information from the message .

At the server end this is the code to read

```
uint32 pendingData = 0;
        rcvSocket->HasPendingData(pendingData); //rcvSocket is the serversside socket 
        if (pendingData == 0)
        {
            UE_LOG(PVCConnector, Warning, TEXT("Lost connection to client."));



            break;
        }

TArray<char> newData;  //customized Array template
        newData.InsertZeroed(0, pendingData);
        int32 bytesRead = 0;
        rcvSocket->Recv(reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(newData.GetData()), pendingData, bytesRead);
        data += newData;
```

However at the server end the  the desired information lands up in the unknown fields of ::google::protobuf::Message . What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem . There were 2 issues

1) The way I was converting to ByteArray
   I replaced

```
 QByteArray byteArray =  QByteArray::fromRawData(static_cast<const char*>(data.data()), data.size());
```

with

```
QByteArray *byteArray =  new QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data.data()), data.size());
```

2) The way I was sending the message on the socket . I just used

```
const int nbBytes = itM->second->write(qByteArray);
```

instead of using QTextStream

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem whe I have been sending big enough messages. We decide, that this happens when message divided into several net packages. We use blobs to prevent that, and it works. About blobs, its technique [to send message length, before message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634483/send-binary-file-over-tcp-ip-connection)

Comment: My message is hardly 30 bytes in size

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to read the data from the socket? There is no guarantee about how much data you will get from each read, the network driver could give you a single byte at a time if it wanted, so you do probably need to send the length then read until you have received that much data, as described by @R.Mazgutov. Even if it generally works without doing that, it is not guaranteed to always do so, so could be brittle. See [Streaming Multiple Messages](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#streaming).

Comment: I also observed that the google protobuf's ParseFromArray APi is populating the unknown fields

Comment: I am setting the codec as UTF-8 ..could this be the issue ?

Comment: I dont think so, that methods works with bytes, not strings. What do you mean when say: unknown field? Can u serialize object, and then parse it back? Is it ok? Can u send some string via your code, and check it another side